# Getting Token Eof Expected when using a IF function with Text.Contains

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

Hello I am getting a 'Token Eof Expected' Error when trying to use a nested if statement with Text.Contains function.

```
if Text.Contains([Status],"A") then "A"
else
Text.Contains([Status],"B") then "B"
else
"C"
```

So here I am trying to get 'A' if 'A' is present, then 'B' id 'B' is present or 'C' for anything else in the string. Here 'Status' is my list/column.

PowerQuery is highlighting the second then as the problem.

On the other hand the below code works perfectly.

```
if Text.Contains([Status],"A") then "A"
else "B"
```

I was able to go around this problem by using 3 additional steps.

```
1st Step
if Text.Contains([Status],"A") then "A" else null
Outputs a column with name 'Status1'

2nd Step
if Text.Contains([Status],"B") then "B" else "C"
Outputs a column with name 'Status2'

3rd Step
if [Status1] = null then [Status2] else [Status1]
```

It gets the job done but it is not elegant.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for the final condition, you need to repeat `if` after `else`:

```
 if Text.Contains([Status], "A") then
    "A"
  else if Text.Contains([Status], "B") then
    "B"
  else
    "C"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That solves the issue. Next time I will go through the documentation more attentively.